# How do I pass a configuration to KinWebBrowserViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to find the correct syntax everywhere and I'm just not understanding it.

How do I pass a configuration to KinWebBrowserViewController?

Here's the KinWebBrowserViewController code converted to Swift (I can also provide the original Objective-C)

```
/*
 Initialize a basic KINWebBrowserViewController instance for push onto navigation stack

 Ideal for use with UINavigationController pushViewController:animated: or initWithRootViewController:

 Optionally specify KINWebBrowser options or WKWebConfiguration
 */
class func webBrowser() -> KINWebBrowserViewController? {
}

class func webBrowser(with configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration?) -> KINWebBrowserViewController? {
}
```

And here's where the browser is instantiated:

```
enum WebviewViewControllerFactory {
    static func make(for url: String) -> WebBrowserViewController {
        let webBrowser  =  WebBrowserViewController()

        webBrowser.showsURLInNavigationBar = false;
        webBrowser.showsPageTitleInNavigationBar = false;

        webBrowser.barTintColor = UIColor.navBackground
        webBrowser.loadURLString(url);

        return webBrowser;
    }
}
```

All I want to do is add the following configuration:

```
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController.add(self, name: "callbackHandler")
```

And add this configuration to the browser.

This seems like it should be easy, but I have been fighting with Swift syntax for hours trying to get what I feel should be fairly simple to work. I've tried initializers, I've tried additional subclassing, I've tried even discarding this and using WkWebView.

How do I set a single configuration on KinWebBrowser?

Comment: Did you get the answer?